# Не работает success в ajax(форма)

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, html-form

Само действие выполняется, а div не меняется в коде формы.
Прочитал все темы и не получилось сделать так, чтобы это нормально работало.

```
< script >
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btn').click(function() {
          // собираем данные с формы
          var clientName = $('#clientName').val();
          var clientPhone = $('#clientPhone').val();
          var clientAuto = $('#vehicle_make').val();
          var clientComment = $('#clientComment').val();
          // отправляем данные
          $.ajax({
            url: "post.php", // куда отправляем
            type: "post", // метод передачи
            dataType: "json", // тип передачи данных
            data: { // что отправляем
              "name": clientName,
              "phone": clientPhone,
              "vehicle_make": clientAuto,
              "message": clientComment
            },
            // после получения ответа сервера
            success: function(i, response) {
              $('.messages').html(response.result); // выводим ответ сервера
            },
            error: function() {
              alert('Not OKay');
            }


          });
          return false;
        });
      }); <
    /script>
```

Вот форма

```
<form id="contact_form" action="" method="post" class="vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid padding-bottom-66 page-margin-top cost-calculator-container contact-form">

  <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-12">

    <div class="wpb_wrapper">

      <div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_inner vc_row-fluid">
        <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-4">
          <div class="vc_column-inner ">
            <div class="wpb_wrapper">
              <div class="cost-calculator-box clearfix">

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_inner vc_row-fluid page-margin-top">
        <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-6">
          <div class="vc_column-inner ">
            <div class="wpb_wrapper">
              <div class="cost-calculator-box cost-calculator-contact clearfix">
                <div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_inner">
                  <label>Контактные данные</label>
                  <div class="messages">.</div>
                </div>
                <div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_inner margin-top-20">
                  <div class="block">
                    <input class="text_input" name="name" id="clientName" type="text" placeholder="Ваше имя">
                  </div>
                  <div class="block">
                    <input class="text_input" name="phone" id="clientPhone" type="tel" placeholder="Ваш номер">
                  </div>
                  <div class="block">

                    <select name="vehicle_make" id="vehicle_make" class="cost-dropdown">
                                                                <option value="" selected="selected">Выберите марку...</option>
                                                                <option value="General Motors">General Motors</option>
                                                                <option value="Land Rover">Land Rover</option>
                                                                <option value="Lexus">Lexus</option>
                                                                <option value="Lincoln">Lincoln</option>
                                                                <option value="Mazda">Mazda</option>
                                                                <option value="Mercedes - Benz">Mercedes - Benz</option></select>

                  </div>
                  <div class="block">
                    <textarea class="margin-top-20" name="message" id="clientComment" placeholder="Additional Questions or Comments"></textarea>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_inner margin-top-20">
                  <button id="btn" class="more display-block submit-contact-form" title="Заказать обратный звонок"><span>Заказать обратный звонок</span></button>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

post.php

```
    $msg_box = ""; // в этой переменной будем хранить сообщения формы
    $errors = array(); // контейнер для ошибок
    // проверяем корректность полей
    if($_POST['name'] == "")    $errors[] = "Поле 'Ваше имя' не заполнено!";
    if($_POST['phone'] == "")   $errors[] = "Поле 'Ваш e-mail' не заполнено!";
    if($_POST['vehicle_make'] == ""){ $clientCar="Не указана";} else { $clientCar = $_POST['vehicle_make'];}
   // if($_POST['message'] == ""){ $clientMessage="-";} else { $clientMessage = $_POST['message'];}

     // если форма без ошибок
    if(empty($errors)){     
        // собираем данные из формы

        date_default_timezone_set('europe/moscow');

    $message = "Дата заявки: " . date("m.d.y G:i") . "\n"
            . "Имя: " . $_POST['name'] . "\n"
            . "Номер: " . $_POST['phone'] . "\n"
            . "Марка: " . $clientCar . "\n"
            . "Комментарий: " . $_POST['message'] . "\n"
    ;

    sendMessage($chat_id, $message);
        // выведем сообщение об успехе
        $msg_box = "<span style='color: green;'>ПУШКА</span><br/>";
    }else{
        // если были ошибки, то выводим их
        $msg_box = "";
        foreach($errors as $one_error){
            $msg_box .= "<span style='color: red;'>$one_error</span><br/>";
        }
    }

    // делаем ответ на клиентскую часть в формате JSON
    echo json_encode(array(
        'result' => $msg_box
    ));

function sendMessage($chat_id, $message) {
    file_get_contents($GLOBALS['api'] . '/sendMessage?chat_id=' . $chat_id . '&text=' . urlencode($message));
}
function is_empty(&$var)
{
    return !($var || (is_scalar($var) && strlen($var)));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замените

```
success: function(i, response) {
    $('.messages').html(response.result); // выводим ответ сервера
}
```

на

```
success: function(response) {
    $('.messages').html(response.result); // выводим ответ сервера
}
```

> success Type: Function(data, textStatus, jqXHR).
>    [Подробнее](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Спасибо, помогло! Правда, заметил еще проблему: после отправки формы, поля как бы подвисают, с чем это может быть связано, не подскажете?

Comment: @Kir всегда пожалуйста. Можно подробнее, плюс если есть скриншоты

Comment: Если не заполнять форму, чтобы пришла ошибка и выдало алерт, то потом текстовое поле для комментария не работает, будто подвисло (крутится кружочек, если навести мышь)

Comment: @Kir `error: function() {
              alert('Not OKay');
            }` выполняется только когда сервер выдает ошибка! Посмотрите `console`